# Move multiple directories at once, how?

Tags: linux, mv

In `directory_1`, I have numerous subdirectories with names consisting only of digits, and some of these need to be moved to `directory_BB`:

```
directory_1
  3245561
  8978554
  2345556
  3453456
  6873253

directory_BB
  order/sorting not important
```

How can I move multiple arbitrary subdirectories (100+) at once when the names of each are randomized every time?

Comment: What you are asking is still very unclear (even after your "answer" - and don't do that, edit the question instead).   If you have specific directories you want to move you can supply multiple directories to the mv command, the last one is taken as the dest - so *mv /path/to/a /path/to/b /newpath*   will move "a"  and" b"and all their subdirectories into be into /newpath.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you would use a regular expression to select the directories you want to move and the `mv` command to move them.
If, within directory__1, there are only directories (no files, links, etc) and you want to move them all, then it would be enough to use `*` as a wild card.

```
mv /path/to/directory_1/* /path/to/directory_bb
```

Comment: Note: `*` here is a globbing pattern (filename expansion pattern). It's not a regular expression.

Comment: Hm, yes, I can use mv, but in a directory there are about 7000 under directories, of which I want to move 100 or 1000.
How can I do that?

Comment: @webuser57 Then you should edit the question and specify a condition for directories you want to move. "The directory names consist only of digits" looks more like information about all directories (similar to "there are no spaces, newlines nor unprintable characters in directory names"). Is this a condition according to which we should pick directories from a larger set?

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is unclear. You need to move SOME directories from one place to another, but we don't know which condition each directory need to check in order to be moved.
My gut feeling is that you may solve that by using the `find` command, doing something like:

```
find directory_1 -[PROPERTY] [EXPRESSION] -exec mv directory_BB {} \;
```

You can find a lot of examples of the `find` command [here](https://www.tecmint.com/35-practical-examples-of-linux-find-command/).